# Trouble displaying simple text using freemarker

Tags: text, freemarker

I am trying to display following text using freemarker

My *.ftl file ahs following content:
OVERREAD A B

I see that entire line is missing when content is processed by template engine.
Blank line is displayed.

Is OVERREAD a built key word in Freemarker. I don't understand why I cant display that simple text.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: No, it's not a keyword for FreeMarker. It should be displayed as is. Something is wrong outside FreeMarker there.

Comment: ok. Thanks. Will try and see.